# Put social media div in the web page center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put the social media icones of my website in the page center.
But I couldn't.
This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ahgL130/1/

CSS:

```
.table1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:100%
}

.table2{
  font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:1em;
  line-height:1.5;
  max-width:600px;
  padding:0 20px 0 20px;
}

.table3{
   padding:20px;
}

.table4{
 padding-bottom:20px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 align-items: center;
}
.table5{
padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

So please how can I correct my code to get the elements in the page center

Answer (score 3):

You have to update your entire code and use below snippet using `flexbox`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/32x32/000/fff" width="32" height="32">
  </a>
  <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/32x32/000/fff" alt="" width="32" height="32">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .table1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            min-width: 100%
        }
        .table2 {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            line-height: 1.5;
            max-width: 600px;
            padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .table3 {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .table4 {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .table5 {
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div>
        <div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="table1">
            <table role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="table2">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="table3">
                            <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table4">
                                            <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                                        <td height="32" width="42">
                                                            <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                                                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" width="32" height="32">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td height="32" width="42">
                                                            <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                                                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" width="32" height="32">
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="table5">
                                            <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                                <img src="" alt="" width="136" height="50">
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Table `align:center`

```
<div>
    <div lang="en"  class="table1">
        <table align="center" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="table2">
            <tbody>

                <tr>

                    <td class="table3">
                        <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table4">

                                        <table align="center" role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="210">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="32" width="42">
                                                        <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                                            <img src="" width="32" height="32" >
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td height="32" width="42">
                                                        <a href="" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                                            <img src="" width="32" height="32" >
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="table5" style="text-align:center">
                                        <a href=""  target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="">
                                            <img src="" alt="" width="136" height="50">
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/f2gs7erq/5/

Comment: Maybe using tables for "center this div" is a bit too much when you could use flexboxes and grid system ?